# OracleType.Char to OracleDbType.??? - ODP.NET 12.1 conversion

Tags: c#, oracle11g, odp.net, oracleclient

We have a 11gr2 table containing `CHAR(16 BYTE)` columns.

In C# using Microsoft's deprecated `OracleClient` I can build a parameterised query containing a C# string bind variable into OracleType.Char. The query works.

```
    OracleParameter ci = new OracleParameter();
    ci.ParameterName = "ci";
    ci.OracleType = OracleType.Char;
    ci.Value = "A020";

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, OraConn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(ci);
```

When migrating to *ODP.NET 12.1* I get a cast error when using `OracleDbType.Char`.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("cc", OracleDbType.Char).Value = "A020");
```

What type of `OracleDbType` should I use?

Comment: First things first: Did you realize that ODP.NET defaults to Bind by Position where the MS Oracle Client defaults to bindbyname? You can set BindbyName=true in ODP.NET to get the OracleClient behavior. Please confirm this is not the cause of your issue.

Comment: @Christian - I can confirm bindbyvalue is not the issue - many thanks

Comment: It's not "bindbyVALUE"......... In OracleClient the parameter name is all that needs to match the placeholders. In ODP.NET, the order in which you create the parameters is all important. It's a very common cause of this error in people doing migrations.

Comment: Sorry recalled incorrectly - bindbyname is not the issue

Answer (score 0):

Use OracleDbType.NVarchar2. Additionally you can specify data size